# How to use a function in "final_snapshot_identifier" of "aws_db_instance"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to Terraform. I would like to build RDS (MySQL) using Terraform and make its snapshot name contain timestamp. How can I code to realize this?

I checked the official document about `timestamp()` function (https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/timestamp#examples), but the page does not clearly mention how to use `timestamp()` in `.tf` files.

**Code**

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "db-dev" {
    identifier                = "db-dev"
    allocated_storage         = 30
    storage_type              = "gp2"
    engine                    = "mysql"
    engine_version            = "8.0.27"
    instance_class            = "db.t3.micro"
    db_name                   = "test"
    username                  = "admin"
    password                  = "admin"
    port                      = 3306
    publicly_accessible       = false
    availability_zone         = "${var.az_1_private}"
    security_group_names      = []
    vpc_security_group_ids    = ["${aws_security_group.sg-1-dev.id}"]
    db_subnet_group_name      = "db-dev-subnet"
    parameter_group_name      = "db-dev-parameter"
    multi_az                  = false
    backup_retention_period   = 0
    backup_window             = "04:30-05:00"
    maintenance_window        = "wed:01:00-wed:03:00"
    final_snapshot_identifier = "db-dev-${timestamp()}"
}
```

Error message

```
Error: invalid value for final_snapshot_identifier (must only contain alphanumeric characters and hyphens)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

timestamp returns a UTC timestamp string like `2022-05-02T05:20:12Z` which includes colons for the time part of the timestamp.

Colons are not permitted to be in snapshot names.

You can use the [`formatdate`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/formatdate) function to format the timestamp to any format that only includes alphanumeric & hyphen characters.

For example, this should work:

```
final_snapshot_identifier = "db-dev-${formatdate('YYYYMMDDhhmmss', timestamp())}"
```

Comment: Ermiya's original answer before his edit was good. The currently posted answer has errors because of the directional quotes and there the year has only 3 "Y"s.

Comment: @mmalone Oh sorry, I didn’t notice - rolled back! Thanks!